# Position edit and delete icons below an image

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. I am tryng to create a layout where I have an image and I want to add edit and delete icons below it or overlay them on the bottom right corner of the image. So far I have been able to get the image and icons in the following style:

[image]

I am using materialize css and litbox, in my materialize css file I added the following attributes for my gallery and I have the following HTML:

```css
gallery {
  margin: 100px 250px;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: .5s;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery center">
  <a href="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
    <img src="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg">
  </a>
  <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">delete</i>
  <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">edit</i>
</div>
```

My question is, how do I align the edit and delete icons below the image in the bottom right corner? The page will have a lot of images and each image is going to have these icons below them.

[image]

Appreciate the help guys!

Comment: tried  break tag <br/>  ???

Comment: give your image the css property block; `display:block;`

Comment: tried that just now but now the image is to the left and icons are on the right.

Comment: You have changed the question. Do you want images to be in a column and add content to the right, or do you want a grid with several columns? .. You can do these things with a `<ul>` or look up grid css.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
       <div class="gallery center">
        <a href="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
            <img src="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg">
        </a>

        <br/>
        <div style="float:right;text-align:right;width:50%;">
          <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">delete</i>
          <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">edit</i>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: That actuall takes the image to the far left and the icons to the far right. I am testing with one image right now and it distributes the image and icons in the gallery

Answer (score 0):

You need to change teh behaviour of your image element. The image is an inline element. By adding the display:block you can change that.

```css
gallery {
  margin: 100px 250px;
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: .5s;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery center">
  <a href="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
  <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">delete</i>
  <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">edit</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `.gallery`'s changes.

```css
.gallery {
  margin: 100px 250px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}

.gallery img{
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: .5s;
}

.gallery img:hover{
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery center">
  <a href="https://picsum.photos/458/354" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/458/354">
  </a>
  <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">delete</i>
  <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">edit</i>
</div>
```

Comment: I am almost there, how should I wrap each image and icons in a single tag so that when I use a loop I can call that html again and again?

Comment: You don't need to change your html structure and just put `<div class="gallery center"> ... </div>` in your loop will be fine.

Comment: You are welcome. Would you consider to Accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

See below snippet

```css
gallery {
  margin: 100px 250px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.gallery img{
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: .5s;

}

.gallery img:hover{
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.css" />

<div class="gallery center">
            <a href="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/flag-of-pakistan-picture-id639704684?k=6&m=639704684&s=612x612&w=0&h=2DyKjXPQlsLEiBXecchlyTpCy3_TcJ7BZp-pew_LL0I=">
            </a>
            <div class="icon">
            <i class="material-icons zmdi  zmdi-delete blue-grey-text">delete</i>
            <i class="material-icons zmdi  zmdi-edit blue-grey-text">edit</i>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Alternatively you can do  this using `display:block` and use a fix width for  `.gallery` class

Comment: and @ Chaska, guys when I use your approach I get multiple images in a single column. Update the image in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the links inside a div.

```
<div class="gallery center">
            <a href="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
                <img src="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg">
            </a>
           <div>
                <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">delete</i>
                <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">edit</i>
           </div>
</div>
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
    <style>

    gallery {
      margin: 100px 250px;
    }

    .gallery img{
      width: 150px;
      padding: 5px;
      filter: grayscale(100%);

      transition: .5s;

    }
    .pos
    {
        margin-left:100px;
    }
    .gallery img:hover{
      filter: grayscale(0);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
     </style>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

   <div class="gallery center">
                <a href="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
 <img src="./public/images/demogallery/1.jpg"></a>

               <div class="pos">

                    <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">delete</i>
                    <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">edit</i>
                </div>  
         </div>
```